# Javascript problems with asynchronous objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to filter some data that I get from a `JSON` object like so :

```
if (this.targetaudiencefilter == 'prezent') {
  targetaudience = $.extend(true, {}, this.OrganizationMetadata.targetaudience)

  for (const key in targetaudience) {
    targetaudience[key].audience = Object.keys(targetaudience[key].audience).reduce(function(presentlist) {
      prezentaudience = Object.values(ParticipationList.UsersMetadata).filter(e => e.task.attendance == '30');
      for (let item in prezentaudience) {
        presentlist[prezentaudience[item].id] = prezentaudience[item].firstname;
      }
      return presentlist;
    }, {});

  }
}
```

The object I am getting the data from `OrganizationMetadata.targetaudience` has 20 records in total, and from the filtering I get 5 records on `targetaudience`, which is correct,
but `targetaudience` shows 5 records even if I `console.log` before the `for`block (if I remove the `for` block, it shows 20).

Any idea what is causing this? Does it even have anything to do with asynchronization?

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(targetaudience.length)` before the `for` block

Comment: `targetaudience` is an object. The length is undefined. But it has two other objects inside, one of which has 5 records , but it should have 20 before filtering, as `this.OrganizationMetadata.targetaudience` has two objects, one of which has 20.

Comment: Fun fact, even if I set the `for` block inside a timeout, the console before the timout, still prints 5, even though the filtering hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Why does the `reduce` callback function only take one argument? It needs two arguments: the accumulator object and the current element of the iteration.

Comment: And it should do something with the current iteration item. Your callback function is just processing the same `prezentaudience` array each time.

Comment: console.log() shows objects at the time of evaluation